# How to make a datepicker choose only from a day after current day

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I used the following jQuery code to get the dates into my input fields in order to have a `"from"` and `"to"` date inputs.

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function (date) {
        var dt2 = $('#dt2');
        var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        dt2.datepicker('setDate', minDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 360);
        //sets dt2 maxDate to the last day of 30 days window
        dt2.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
        dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
        $(this).datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate);
    }
});
$('#dt2').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"
});
```

If I choose the first date as 19-04-2017, automatically the second date starts from 19-04-2017 only.
Question is: How can I make my second date only start counting one day after the first chosen date?

Meaning it would be 20-04-2017 instead of 19...

[Here you can see my entire fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wosley_Alarico/rrxhywwt/2/)

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only this (change `onSelect` like given below):-

```
onSelect: function (date) {
    var dt2 = $('#dt2');
    var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate','+1d');
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1); 
    dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
    dt2.datepicker('setDate', startDate);
}
```

Comment: The answer does work. The only change it made is that as soon as I load the site, I do not end up seeing the input field placeholder, but the date already. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Never mind it works perfectly. Appreciate the support

Comment: @WosleyAlarico  glad to help you.:):)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#thedate').datepicker({
    minDate: "+1",
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
});
$('#thedate').datepicker("setDate", "+1");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2967/)

Comment: There is only one date input in your snippet. Can you make it work accordingly with 2 dates? A "from date" where you can choose any date, and a "to" date that can only start from a day after the day of the "from" date. Hope I made some sense

Comment: I just added my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it Will work As u said

```
 $(function(){

    $('#FromDate').datepicker({
        minDate: "1",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onSelect: function () {
            var dt2 = $('#ToDate');
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
            var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            dt2.datepicker('setDate', startDate);
            dt2.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
        }
    });


});

$(function(){

        $('#ToDate').datepicker({
                minDate: "0",
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });

});
```